# Как задать путь через folderbrowserdialog для picture box visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Вот строчка кода из программы, надо этот путь

```
@"C:\Users\ZULFAT\Desktop\Cars\avtophoto\
```

задавать через

```
folderbrowserdialog C# pictureBox9.ImageLocation = @"C:\\Users\ZULFAT\Desktop\Cars\avtophoto\"dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[21].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"путь к файлу");`

Comment: Image.FromFile не содержит такого определения

Comment: [Содержит](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Ошибка CS0103 Имя "ImageFromFile" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: Как теперь задать путь через folderbrowserdialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала создадим формочку, добавим `PictureBox` и `Button`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмем 2 раза ЛКМ по `button1` в конструкторе, чтобы появился обработчик события. В него напишем следующий код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath)
                                                .Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpeg") 
                                                            || x.EndsWith(".jpg") 
                                                            || x.EndsWith(".bmp") 
                                                            || x.EndsWith(".png"))
                                                .Select(x => new { Path = x }).ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = files;
        }
}
```

Затем, откроем свойства `datagridview1` и выберем параметр `CellContentDoubleClick`, нажмем туда 2 раза ЛКМ, и напишем следующий код:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string path = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Есть папка фоток @"C:\Users\ZULFAT\Desktop\Cars\avtophoto\, нужно задавать путь к нему через folderbrowserdialog но конечный файл (фото.jpg) брать из dataGridView по клику по строчке

Comment: @ЗульфатХамидуллин изменил ответ